# Unable to correctly input scanned string into 2D array

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

I am to read the file and compile running totals on the salespeople and also their total for each individual product and the overall total for each product. I must store all of that in a 2D array(Lists are not allowed) and print in a certain format.

The text file is documented as such:

```
1,4,10.20
2,2,17.20
etc 
etc
```

Column1 is personID Column 2 is product number column 3 is the amount

My code attempts to split each line into a string and then further split each value to an index and then store it within a 2D array. I feel silly but I am having a conversion error. No matter what I do I cannot make the array store amount in an acceptable format. I can't create the array as a double for some reason. It returns as terminated when I attempt to compile. My professor said an integer should work and I simply cannot get accurate summing.

```
package HW1;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class salesList {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
          Scanner salesList;
          salesList = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\mjwag\\OneDrive\\cs151/salesList.txt"));
          
         while  (salesList.hasNext())  {
             Scanner file = salesList;
             file.nextLine();
             String line = file.nextLine();
             String[] lineArray = line.split(",");
             int personID = Integer.parseInt(lineArray[0]);
             int product = Integer.parseInt(lineArray[1]);
             int amount = Integer.parseInt(lineArray[2]);
             int [][] sales = new int[4][6];
             sales[personID-1][product-1] += amount;
             
            }
         
      }
}
```

Comment: the sales array is being recreated on each iteration. keep it outside the loop to preserve the 'changes' for each line processed. I highly recommend getting used to using a debugger and stepping through the code line by line. Let me know if you want any specific recommendations, and welcome to the world of programming :)

Comment: DO you mean the instantiation of the array outside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to store both integers and doubles in an array is to use `Number`, which is a superclass of both `Integer` and `Double`. For example:

```java
Number[][] sales = new Number[4][6];
...
sales[0][0] = 1;
sales[0][1] = 4.5;
```

Alternatively, as you've discussed with your professor, it's possible to convert a double to an integer and lose the numbers after the decimal point. This can be done as follows:

```java
double val = 4.5;
int intVal = (int) val;
```

Comment: I changed the array to a Number array and moved it outside the loop but I am getting the following error:  The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) Number, double.

I changed the amount to a double and changed to parseDouble but now I'm getting the above error

Comment: You can use `Number.intValue()` and `Number.doubleValue()` to get an `int` and `double` respectively. Since you already know which values are integers and which are doubles, there is no need to check for that.

Comment: I guess I am still confused in the context of my code. I created an array of Number type and I am simply trying to store the information with the line:    sales[personID-1][product-1] += amount;
The aforementioned error is what I do not understand.

Comment: You will have to do either `sales[personID-1][product-1] = sales[personID-1][product-1].intValue() + amount;` or `sales[personID-1][product-1] = sales[personID-1][product-1].doubleValue() + amount;` depending on whether the stored value is an integer or a double.

Comment: SO this essentially retrieves the last double in said slot and adds the amount to it? So it should further increment?

Now I get the following error when trying to assign the increment.
 Cannot invoke "java.lang.Number.doubleValue()" because "sales[...][...]" is null

 I am guessing this is because on the very first line I am attempting to pull a double from a null that was initiated outside of the loop? Also thank you very much for the help so far!

Comment: Oh, you do have to initialize the values You can loop over the entire `sales` array and set the values to 0 or 0.0 where you are working with integers and doubles respectively. If you feel like this answer has helped, then you should mark it as the accepted answer and optionally upvote it as well ;)